# Node.JS, C++ module: why I have segfault when I try to call Length method of Local<Array>?

Tags: c++, node.js, segmentation-fault

When I call `func()` from js code and `func()` calls `arr->Length()` then I have `segfault`.

But somethimes I have strange random values in `stdout`: `283132217, -1222622919, -42974919, -112180935, 997212473, -1412415175.`

Here's example:

```
#include <node.h>

using namespace v8;

Local<Array> arr = Array::New();

Handle<Value> func(const Arguments &args)
{
    HandleScope scope;

    printf("%d\n", arr->Length());

    return scope.Close(Undefined());
}

void init(Handle<Object> target)
{

    target->Set( String::NewSymbol("func"),
                 FunctionTemplate::New(func)->GetFunction() );

}

NODE_MODULE(ctest, init);
```

Comment: Strange values and crashes is a strong indicator that you have some undefined behavior in your code. Do you have any compiler warnings? Those are often an indicator of undefined behaviors. If you don't have warnings, then you might want to enable more (for GCC/clang add e.g. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`).

Comment: I'm guessing your array is getting garbage collected.  It's not clear what handle scope that local array belongs to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not expert on v8, but I can solve problem like this:

```
Persistent<Array> arr = Persistent<Array>::New(Array::New());


Handle<Value> func(const Arguments &args)
{
    HandleScope scope;

    printf("%d\n", arr->Length());

    return scope.Close(Undefined());
}
```

Or put local handle to your function:

```
Handle<Value> func(const Arguments &args)
{
    HandleScope scope;
    Local<Array> arr = Array::New();

    printf("%d\n", arr->Length());

    return scope.Close(Undefined());
}
```

Comment: I still wait for better answers.

Comment: I believe the first half of the answer is the "right" one -- it's not clear from the node.js require loader what `HandleScope` the global `arr` with a `Local` scope belongs to, so it could get GC'd at any time.

Comment: Thanks! It's my solution:
`Persistent<Array> arr = Persistent<Array>::New(Array::New());`